# python getting 500 error on https cpanel python setup

Tags: python

i am creating my first python telegram bot using webhook requst but i am getting 500 error

Web Url Showing This Error

`500 Internal Server Error An internal server error has occured.`

Terminal Giving Me This error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/predictw/python_app/app.py", line 155, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home2/predictw/python_app/app.py", line 123, in main
    chat_id=get_chat_id(data)
  File "/home2/predictw/python_app/app.py", line 12, in get_chat_id
    chat_id = data['message']['chat']['id']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

and here my codes...

```
import requests
import json
import base64
import sys

from bottle import (
    run, post, response, request as bottle_request
)
BOT_URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot646440835:AAExHQEuBdfsdfsdoGwAfCOGRv8XGo2qw_k/' # <--- add your telegram token here; it should be like https://api.telegram.org/bot12345678:SOMErAn2dom/
def get_chat_id(data):

    chat_id = data['message']['chat']['id']
    return chat_id

def get_username(data):
   
    username = data['message']['chat']['username']
    return username

def get_message(data):
 
    if 'message' in data and 'text' in data['message']:
      return data['message']['text']
    else:
      return data['message']['caption']

    return message_text
   
def send_message(prepared_data):
    """
    Prepared data should be json which includes at least `chat_id` and `text`
    """
    message_url = BOT_URL + 'sendMessage'
    requests.post(message_url, json=prepared_data)  # don't forget to make import requests lib
    
def change_text_message(text):
    """
    To enable turning our message inside out
    """
    return text[::-1]

def prepare_data_for_answer(data):
    # answer = change_text_message(get_message(data))
    json_data = {
        "chat_id": get_chat_id(data),
        "text": get_message(data),
        'parse_mode': "HTML",
    }
    return json_data

def inlinekeyboard(data,keyboard):
    json_data= {
        'chat_id': get_chat_id(data),
        'text': '<b>You Need To Login Open Below Link To Login..</b>',
        'parse_mode': "HTML",
        'reply_markup': json.dumps({
            'inline_keyboard': keyboard,
            "resize_keyboard": True,
            'one_time_keyboard': False
        })
    }
    return json_data

def prepare_data_for_check(data):
    
    json_data = {
        "telegram_id": get_chat_id(data),
        "method": 'check_tgid',
    }
    return json_data
def prepare_data_for_shortLink(link):
    
    json_data = {
        "link": link,
        "method": 'short_link',
    }

    return json_data
def shortLink(prepared_data):
#    print(prepared_data)
   response = requests.post('https://shortlink_domain.com/api.php', data=prepared_data)
#    print(response.text)  # Print the response content
   data = json.loads(response.text)
   if data['status'] == 'success':
        return data['message']
   else:
        return False

def check_user_status(prepared_data):

      response = requests.post('https://status_domain.com/apiV2.php', data=prepared_data)
    #   print(response.text)  # Print the response content
    #   data = response.text.json
      data = json.loads(response.text)
      if data['statusCode'] == '1':
        return True
      else:
        return False

def create_deep(prepared_data):

     response = requests.post('https://deep_link.com/ajax.php', data=prepared_data)
    #  print(response.text)  # Print the response content
     data = json.loads(response.text)
     return data

@post('/')
def main():
    
    data = bottle_request.json
  
    # print(bottle_request.json)
    # answer_data = prepare_data_for_answer(data)
    # send_message(answer_data) 
    # send_message(prepare_data_for_login(data))  
    # print(answer_data)

    chat_id=get_chat_id(data)
    # print(chat_id)
    # print(base64.b64encode(str(chat_id).encode()).decode())

    if check_user_status(prepare_data_for_check(data)):
        # print('done')

        # decoded_text=decode_text(bottle_request.json)

        created_deep=create_deep({'submit': 'yes', 'link': get_message(data), 'telegran_id': chat_id})['data']

        send_message({"chat_id": chat_id,"text": created_deep,'parse_mode': "HTML", "disable_web_page_preview" : True}) 
        # user logined ...
        return
    else : 
        # print('galat')
        shortLinks=shortLink(prepare_data_for_shortLink("https://login_api.com?id="+base64.b64encode(str(chat_id).encode()).decode()))

    if(shortLinks):

        forLogin=inlinekeyboard(data, [[{"text": "Log in", "url": shortLinks}]])
        send_message(forLogin) 
        return 
    else: 
        send_message({"chat_id": get_chat_id(data),"text": '<b>Start Again.</b>','parse_mode': "HTML"}) 
        return 

    # <--- function for sending answer
  
    return response  # status 200 OK by default
if __name__ == '__main__':
  
     main()
```

i am trying to hsot this in my cpanel https doamin host but python app url showing  500
Internal Server Error hopw to i solve it please help me on this.

Comment: The 500 error is completely predictable if the code doesn't work, but it also doesn't reveal anything more than that the code doesn't work. You will need to debug it to figure out why you get a `None` where you don't expect one.